# Search box in network Plot

Tags: html, r, rhtml, networkd3

I have created a Network of protein mutations using the  `forceNetwork()` function of the `networkD3` package. It get's rendered on the RStudio's "Viewer" pane.

I can then save this as an HTML file, for sharing, with the dynamic nature (like clicking nodes, highlighting connections etc) preserved.

A png version of my network plot looks like below: 
[image]

This is a representation of a top 20% in my original data, and the complete data looks even more huge and complex.

I need to be able to add a search to this forceNetwork, so that then specific nodes can be located in a complex network. The javascript or jquery part of this can be easily achieved by editing the copy of package networkD3 and repackaging. But my main challenge is adding the html code for including a search box.

My main R code looks like this:

```
library(networkD3)
library(XLConnect)

wb <- loadWorkbook("input.xlsx")
nodes <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet="Node", startRow = 1, startCol = 1, header = TRUE)
links <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet="Edges", startRow = 1, startCol = 1, header = TRUE)


fn <- forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes,
                   Source = "Source", Target = "ID", Value = "Combo",
                   NodeID = "Mutation", linkDistance = JS('function(d){return d.value * 50;}'), 
                   Nodesize = "IF", Group = "Combo", radiusCalculation = JS("d.nodesize+6"),
                   zoom = T, bounded = F, legend = T, 
                   opacity = 0.8,
                   fontSize = 16 )

fn
```

My inspiration has come from the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simonraper/Bf5nM/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=Bf5nM) by Simon Raper.
What would be the best way to include a search in this situation? The option I have thought of is to first save the rendering as an html. Then read and edit the html and insert the piece of code for the search. 
I tried to use Rhtml for this, but it doesn't seem trivial. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although I'm not crazy about this interactivity, I thought it would be a good opportunity for demonstrating how to use `htmltools` with `htmlwidgets`.  Later, I will recreate with `crosstalk`, but for now, here is how I would replicate the example provided.

#### direct replication

```
library(htmltools)
library(networkD3)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

# make a forceNetwork as shown in ?forceNetwork
fn <- forceNetwork(
  Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source",
  Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
  Group = "group", opacity = 0.4, zoom = TRUE
)

fn <- htmlwidgets::onRender(
  fn,
  '
function(el,x){
debugger;
  var optArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < x.nodes.name.length - 1; i++) {
    optArray.push(x.nodes.name[i]);
  }

  optArray = optArray.sort();

  $(function () {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
      source: optArray
    });
  });

  d3.select(".ui-widget button").node().onclick=searchNode;

  function searchNode() {
    debugger;
    //find the node

    var selectedVal = document.getElementById("search").value;
    var svg = d3.select(el).select("svg");
    var node = d3.select(el).selectAll(".node");

    if (selectedVal == "none") {
      node.style("stroke", "white").style("stroke-width", "1");
    } else {
      var selected = node.filter(function (d, i) {
        return d.name != selectedVal;
      });
      selected.style("opacity", "0");
      var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      link.style("opacity", "0");
      d3.selectAll(".node, .link").transition()
        .duration(5000)
        .style("opacity", 1);
    }
  }
}  
  '
)

browsable(
  attachDependencies(
    tagList(
      tags$head(
        tags$link(
          href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css",
          rel="stylesheet"
        )
      ),
      HTML(
  '
  <div class="ui-widget">
      <input id="search">
      <button type="button">Search</button>
  </div>
  '     
      ),
      fn
    ),
    list(
      rmarkdown::html_dependency_jquery(),
      rmarkdown::html_dependency_jqueryui()
    )
  )
)
```

#### crosstalk version

*note: crosstalk is experimental, so this might change*

I did not spend time to optimize and perfect, but here is a version that sort-of does the same thing as the example but using `crosstalk` instead of custom code and a `jquery-ui` autocomplete.

```
library(htmltools)
library(networkD3)


# demonstrate with experimental crosstalk
#  this will get much easier once we start converting
#  htmlwidgets to work natively with crosstalk

#devtoools::install_github("rstudio/crosstalk")
library(crosstalk)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

# make a forceNetwork as shown in ?forceNetwork
fn <- forceNetwork(
  Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source",
  Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
  Group = "group", opacity = 0.4, zoom = TRUE
)

sd <- SharedData$new(MisNodes, key=~name, group="grp1" )

# no autocomplete so not the same
#  but will use this instead of writing something new
fs <- filter_select(
  id = "filter-node",
  label = "Search Nodes",
  sharedData = sd,
  group = ~name
)

fn <- htmlwidgets::onRender(
  fn,
'
function(el,x){
  // get the crosstalk group
  //  we used grp1 in the SharedData from R
  var ct_grp = crosstalk.group("grp1");
debugger;
  ct_grp
    .var("filter")
    .on("change", function(val){searchNode(val.value)});

  function searchNode(filter_nodes) {
    debugger;
    //find the node
    var selectedVal = filter_nodes? filter_nodes : [];
    var svg = d3.select(el).select("svg");
    var node = d3.select(el).selectAll(".node");

    if (selectedVal.length===0) {
      node.style("opacity", "1");
      svg.selectAll(".link").style("opacity","1");
    } else {
      var selected = node.filter(function (d, i) {
        return selectedVal.indexOf(d.name) >= 0;
      });
      node.style("opacity","0");
      selected.style("opacity", "1");
      var link = svg.selectAll(".link").style("opacity", "0");
      /*
      svg.selectAll(".node, .link").transition()
        .duration(5000)
        .style("opacity", 1);
      */
    }
  }
}  
'
)

browsable(
  tagList(
    fs,
    fn
  )
)
```

Comment: see http://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/fff10346123c40db25cdc9e40b52dd5d for an even more full-featured experiment

Comment: Is the first code example still working? As I search for something, click on the node I want the network seems to re-render however no node is selected

Comment: Nevermind this  isn't that useful for big networks (>1000 nodes) as the search won't zoom in on the node

Comment: Both the soulutions do not show search box in R(3.6.3), htmltools(0.4.0), networkD3(0.4.9000), crosstalk(1.0.0)