# Highlighting multiple nodes in networkD3

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, networkd3

I have been building a force directed Network from `networkD3` using the `forceNetwork` method.

The graph looks like :
[image]
I am able to highlight a single node (and it's neighbors) and fade out others and that looks like:

[image]

The code for this is based on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simonraper/jz2AU/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=jz2AU), except that I have linked the node value to a search box, for which I had received help in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486906/search-box-in-network-plot)

Now I expanded my search to have a list of node names. And I need all the nodes in that list to get highlighted and rest to fade. How do I alter properties of a selected list of node objects?

Comment: If you show us your code, I could help you. It's too hard to piece together what you're working with based on multiple examples that you have modified. What type of object is your selected list of node objects?