# R: networkD3 add zoom function

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, networkd3

There is another question on stackoverflow concerning searching for nodes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486906/search-box-in-network-plot). I would love to have this for my network, however due to its size (> 1000 nodes) a highlighting won't work. Well it works, but the nodes are quite small and thus when there is only one node visible its really hard to spot this on a whole screen. Therefore I want the search function to zoom in on the node instead.
I will copy and paste the answer code from the other question here:

```
library(htmltools)
library(networkD3)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

# make a forceNetwork as shown in ?forceNetwork
fn <- forceNetwork(
  Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source",
  Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
  Group = "group", opacity = 0.4, zoom = TRUE
)

fn <- htmlwidgets::onRender(
  fn,
  '
function(el,x){
debugger;
  var optArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < x.nodes.name.length - 1; i++) {
    optArray.push(x.nodes.name[i]);
  }

  optArray = optArray.sort();

  $(function () {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
      source: optArray
    });
  });

  d3.select(".ui-widget button").node().onclick=searchNode;

  function searchNode() {
    debugger;
    //find the node

    var selectedVal = document.getElementById("search").value;
    var svg = d3.select(el).select("svg");
    var node = d3.select(el).selectAll(".node");

    if (selectedVal == "none") {
      node.style("stroke", "white").style("stroke-width", "1");
    } else {
      var selected = node.filter(function (d, i) {
        return d.name != selectedVal;
      });
      selected.style("opacity", "0");
      var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      link.style("opacity", "0");
      d3.selectAll(".node, .link").transition()
        .duration(5000)
        .style("opacity", 1);
    }
  }
}  
  '
)

browsable(
  attachDependencies(
    tagList(
      tags$head(
        tags$link(
          href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css",
          rel="stylesheet"
        )
      ),
      HTML(
  '
  <div class="ui-widget">
      <input id="search">
      <button type="button">Search</button>
  </div>
  '     
      ),
      fn
    ),
    list(
      rmarkdown::html_dependency_jquery(),
      rmarkdown::html_dependency_jqueryui()
    )
  )
)
```

I have looked around at bl.ocks.org and found something that could work [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9656675). Especially this piece of code:

```
svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
  .call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
```

I thought I could simply insert it here:

```
………………> 
selected.style("opacity", "0");
svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
```

This does not seem to work, and with limited knowledge of JavaScript I can't get it to work either. Besides the solution, a short explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @CJYetmam Instead of only highlighting the searched node I also want to zoom in on it

Comment: You'd have to be much more specific. When you have the name for one specific node typed into the search bar and you click the search button, you would want it to zoom all the way into just that node and then zoom back out to the whole network?

Comment: Only zooming in, the user can then zoom out by himself @CJYetman

Comment: Hopefully it is clear now @CJYetman

Comment: It’s clear enough, but it’s not easy to do that level of customization. I don’t have the time to do it.